# Firefox: Slow performance with large blurred elements

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm facing a little problem with Firefox : when there **is large blurred elements displayed on the dom**, everything is stupidly slow.

### A few things I noticed :

- On some modest configurations, a reflow event can even freeze the tab
- On high-end GPU, the FPS is slightly better, so I guess this filter is GPU activated
- Chrome & Safari are running very smoothly
- **Even without animation** the CPU usage is very high and any interaction is laggy

### Ok show me the code

**Make sure to click on expand the window so that all the images can show up**, otherwise the animation will stay smooth.

I am creating a reflow event with a padding animation to intentionally stress the browser, but the overall interactions are laggy.

On a more complex webpage like CodePen the FPS is way worse : https://codepen.io/creaforge/pen/mLPqNg
Even without firing the transform editing this pen shows some performance issue (try to select blocks of code)

```css
div {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  transition: all .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}

div:hover {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

img {
  filter: blur(40px);
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me --> slow animation</div><br/>

<img src="http://www.placecage.com/c/200/600">
<img src="http://www.placecage.com/c/200/610">
<img src="http://www.placecage.com/c/200/620">
<img src="http://www.placecage.com/c/200/630">
<img src="http://www.placecage.com/c/200/640">
```

Comment: Dont use padding for animation , use translate instead , using padding will heavely affect the CPU usage

Comment: This is intentional, I'll edit the question to be more precise!

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem, but a great way to help the Firefox devs would be to take a [performance profile](https://perf-html.io/) and [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=DOM%3A%20Core%20%26%20HTML)!

Comment: Thanks Dexter I didn't had knowledge of this tool. I'll make a few more tests, create an easily reproducible test case & I'll file the bug

Comment: This is a firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=925025 - if you hit this issue feel free to bump it!

Answer (score 0):

Use translate instead of padding. Animating with padding is quite heavy for your computer.

Comment: Yes I am intentionnaly causing a reflow to stress the browser, but even without animation, any interaction is dramaticaly slow. On [this pen](https://codepen.io/creaforge/pen/PeNRVv) editing is laggy in Firefox & smooth in Chrome. I get a 15% CPU jump just by opening the page (high end i7)